# Error in checkout/onepage after Magento patch 6788

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I am a newbie in the Magento programming and I have the following problem:
When I applied the Magento Patch 6788 I can't reach the `www.siteurl.com/checkout/onepage/` anymore.

I think it has something to do with the following:

```
<?php

class MW_Ddate_Model_Ddate extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
  private $inexedDdates = null;

public function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();
    $this->_init('ddate/ddate');
}

public function getNumberOrderFromNow() {
    if(is_null($this->inexedDdates)) {
        $timeFilter = strtotime('- 1 day');
        $collection = $this->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ddate)', array('gteq' => $timeFilter));
        $ddateArray = array();
        foreach ($collection as $ddate) {
            $ddateArray[$ddate->getDtime()][$ddate->getDdate()] = $ddate;
        }

       $this->inexedDdates = $ddateArray;
    }

    return $this->inexedDdates;
 }
}
?>
```

In the logfile there was something said about `->addFieldToFilter('UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ddate)'`

I think the *UNIX_TIMESTAMP* is deprecated when I did the patch.

Does anyone knows how I can solve this problem?

EDIT:
The plugin which I use on the onepage is the Delivery Date from MageWorld

Answer (score 0):

Contact MageWorld and ask them? If they don't support it anymore; test the module with [SUPEE-6788 developer toolbox](https://github.com/rhoerr/supee-6788-toolbox). The toolbox can also fix compatibility issues with modules and the SUPEE-6788 patch. Also have a look at the [technical details of the SUPEE-6788 patch](http://magento.com/security/patches/supee-6788-technical-details) at the "APPSEC-1063, addressing possible SQL injection" section.